# How to add timeout between power off and power on as part of power cycle?

Tags: linux, ipmitool

Is there a linux command or a way to cause a power cycle a system with a timeout/delay in between the power off and power on? Thanks.

Comment: This will be completely hardware-dependent.

Comment: @TrippKinetics - Could you please elaborate more? Thanks. I have seen such timeout settings in bios options, but that works only for hard power failures not the power cycles initiated through OS.

Answer (score 0):

It is a power management feature that is supported by many, but not all, BIOS/UEFI power management feature sets.  The feature should be called "***Resume on RTC Alarm***", or something similar.  Please refer to [*these instructions*](https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-windows-7-system-startup-and-shutdown-on-a-schedule/), which deal with Microsoft Windows 7 for general information regarding this feature.

As far as doing it in Linux is concerned, there is a software package called [`nvram-wakeup`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nvram-wakeup/), which is available by default on many Linux distributions.  The workflow would be to set `nvram-wakeup` to power the machine up 5 minutes after the scheduled shutdown time, and then perform a `shutdown -P {scheduled time}`.